# two emails in the same file php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a php file with two different forms, both forms are for different recipients but when one of the two forms was submited the two forms fired submit, I want to avoid that, i want to submit only the form that is clicked the other one not.

This is my code:

```
<section id="contacto">
    <div class="donveloz"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <h3>Inscribe tu e·commerce</h3>
      <p>Da el siguiente paso para tu negocio.</p>
      <?php
$action=$_REQUEST['action'];
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */
    {
    ?>
      <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="limpio">
          <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
        <input class="name" type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required/>
        <input class="email mitad" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
        <input class="phone mitad derecha error" type="phone" name="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" required/>
        <input class="negocio" type="text" name="ecommerce" placeholder="Nombre de tu e-commerce"/>
        <input class="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Envia tu información" id="submit"/>
      </form>
       <?php
    } 
else                /* send the submitted data */
    {
    $name=$_REQUEST['nombre'];
    $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
    $phone=$_REQUEST['telefono'];
    $commerce=$_REQUEST['ecommerce'];
    $subject="Nuevo ecommerce registrado";
// PREPARE THE BODY OF THE MESSAGE

      $message = '<html><body>';
      $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
      $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_REQUEST['nombre']) . "</td></tr>";
      $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_REQUEST['email']) . "</td></tr>";
      $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Telefono:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_REQUEST['telefono']) . "</td></tr>";
      $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Ecommerce:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_REQUEST['ecommerce']) . "</td></tr>";
      $message .= "</table>";
      $message .= "</body></html>";
      $headers = "From:postulaciones@99minutos.com\r\n";
      $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";



    mail("victor@99minutos.com", $subject, $message,$headers);
    //MESSAGE SHOW WHEN FORM IS SUBMITTED
    echo 'Gracias por registrar tu informacion, en breve nos comunicaremos contigo';

    }  
?>
    </div>
  </section>

  <footer>
    <div class="container">  
      <h4>
        <img src="img/icono99minutos.svg" alt="99minutos"> The fastest shipping <span>for online shopping</span>
      </h4>
      <nav>
        <ul class="izq">
          <li><a href="bolsa.php">Bolsa de trabajo</a></li>
          <li><a href="faq.html">FAQs</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://precise-line-76299minutos.appspot.com/2/delivery/client/login">Iniciar Sesión</a></li>
          <li><a class="boton" href="rastreo.html">Rastrea tu Envío</a></li>
          <li><a class="boton" href="#loginmodal" id="modaltrigger">Conviértete en un Don Veloz</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="der">
          <li><img src="img/email.png" alt="">envios@99minutos.com</li>
          <li><img src="img/phone.png" alt="">(52) 55 6363·1559</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div id="loginmodal" style="display:none;">
    <h1>Se un Don Veloz</h1>
    <?php
    $action=$_REQUEST['action'];
    if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */
    {
    ?>
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="limpio">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
        <label for="username">Nombre:</label>
        <input class="name" type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" id="lineanombre" required/><br>
        <label for="username">Correo:  </label>
        <input class="email mitad" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="lineacorreo" required/><br>
        <label for="username">Telefono:</label>
        <input class="phone mitad derecha error" type="phone" name="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" id="lineatelefono" required/>
        <!--<input class="negocio" type="text" name="ecommerce" placeholder="Nombre de tu e-commerce"/>-->
        <input class="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Envia tu información" id="btnn" onClick="submitForm()"/>
      </form> 

    <?php
    } 
else                /* send the submitted data */
    {
    $name=$_REQUEST['nombre'];
    $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
    $phone=$_REQUEST['telefono'];
    $commerce=$_REQUEST['ecommerce'];
    $subject="Nuevo Aspirante a Don Veloz libre";
// PREPARE THE BODY OF THE MESSAGE

      $message = '<html><body>';
      $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
      $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_REQUEST['nombre']) . "</td></tr>";
      $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_REQUEST['email']) . "</td></tr>";
      $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Telefono:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_REQUEST['telefono']) . "</td></tr>";
      $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Ecommerce:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_REQUEST['ecommerce']) . "</td></tr>";
      $message .= "</table>";
      $message .= "</body></html>";
      $headers = "From:postulaciones@99minutos.com\r\n";
      $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";



    mail("envios@99minutos.com, yesenia@99minutos.com", $subject, $message,$headers);
    echo "Gracias por registarte en breve recibiras un correo";
}

?>



  </div>

  </footer>
```

I use this script for submit the form only one time:

```
onsubmit="document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true";
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add a class in each submit or use the jquery .eq() read this for more information https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/